# Copy all contents of an Amiga harddrive to a PC

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, data-transfer, portable-harddrive, amiga

I have an old Amiga hard disk drive (CP2088 Conner drive). It is a 2.5" IDE drive (see bottom).

How can I connect this to a PC, what software is needed, and how can I convert the entire disk to a [WinUAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAE_%28emulator%29#Project_development) image?

Can a normal 2.5" IDE to 3.5" IDE work?

I understood that I cannot use an IDE/USB box for this?

[image: CP2088 Conner IDE drive]

Comment: If this really is IDE 44 (at least looks like) I don't think that there is a problem connecting the drive to a normal PC (given the correct adapter). But the filesystem might be a problem, I have no idea what FS was used by amiga, some linux distribution should be able to mount and read it though.

Comment: Still, you should probably at least be able to take an image of the drive before the hardware dies (if it is actually still alive) and then proceed to hack at the image.

Comment: Amiga filesystem is called AFFS -> (Amiga Fast File System- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_Fast_File_System). And linux supports it and grub. Might be able to create a virtual image.

Comment: I now got a converter from 3.5" to 2.5" and the drive spins up, in windows it found new hardware, but the name was not even close to anything conner, it look like at the time, drive names was not used to disks, it might not be relevant at all, however in disk management it says that this drive has capacity of "6291552,00 GB" i did not initialize it or anything, in winuae it did not appear under add harddisk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting the drive via a 2.5 inch laptop IDE to regular IDE should work fine. An external USB casing for IDE/[PATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) will also work. However, Windows will not recognise the contents of the drive without extra software. But you will be able to make a backup of the drive via [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) or its Windows equivalent.

According *to [Use WinUAE to access Amiga HDD](http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=60573)*, WinUAE might suffice for this.

Comment: i was thinking about that, first I would like to just copy all data possible, and secondly want to try an attempt on creating an iamge of the drive

Comment: I have an ATA-100 cable, is there any known compatibility issues between these ?

Comment: The 44 pin connector on the old IDE laptop drive differs from regular IDE in two ways: The pins on the connector are spaced closer, and 4 extra 4 pins supply power.  If you love a few hours of finicky work with a soldering iron you could get it to work, but for practical purposes it should not be tried.  Get a 44 pin IDE to 40 pin convertor (and connect the ata / ATA-33, -66, -100 or -133 cable to that).  Those convertors used to be 12 guilders (US $7-ish) in the time that IDE was common.